# How to add dynamic headers in arm template custom connector for Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a logic app workflow where if the property `headers` is added then it shows up `+` button to add headers automatically. I suspect because this is a workflow it happens. But i need same kind of thing in my custom connector which is a `ApiConnection` to a resource. How can i achieve it. I cannot find any documentaion regarding this. I tried several ways in code view , cant seem to get it working.

[image]

Comment: if you define the header object as an array, would it help ?

Comment: Will check and get back